# How can I call a function multiple times from different buttons?

Tags: javascript, function, events

I am building a quiz page using javascript, and want the user to select from a multiple choice and then hit 'Go' to check their answer. Here is the html for the first question:

```
<p class="question">What is the name of Joey's bedtime penguin pal?</p>
<div class="radio">
<div>
    <input type="radio" class="wrong" name="q1">Maurice
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" class="wrong" name="q1">Clunkers
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" class="right" name="q1">Hugsy
</div>
<div class="button">
    <button type="button" class="go">Go</button>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="images/hugsy.jpg" class="image" style="display: none;"
</div>
```

I have created a function which is called by the Go button which informs the user if they are right or not. Here is the javascript:

```
let go = document.querySelector('.go');
let correct = document.querySelector('.right');
let showPic = document.querySelector('img');
let remGo = document.querySelector('button');
let choices = document.querySelector('.radio');
let score = 0;

go.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);

function checkAnswer() {
    if (correct.checked) {
        showPic.classList.remove('image');
        remGo.remove();
        choices.innerHTML = '<h2 style="color: green;">Correct!</h2>';
        score++;
    } else {
        remGo.remove();
        choices.innerHTML = '<h2 style="color: red;">Incorrect</h2>';
    }
}
```

This code works the way I want it to but only for the first question. When I try to call the function again by clicking 'Go' on question 2 nothing happens.

Is there a way to call a function multiple times using different buttons?

Comment: Based on what you describe, yes, that is possible. If you need help with specific code, we need to be able to see the code! Please edit your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response, my code is now displayed

Comment: You cannot add event listeners to classes. It's very strange it works for the first button. Probably the `querySelector` returns the first element of the class.

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector('.go');`
 only selects the first matching element.

To select all elements with the `.go` class you need to use `querySelectorAll`

Then you'll need to assign your event listener to all elements returned.

Here is a minimal example:

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.go');

for (const button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);
}


function checkAnswer() {
    console.log("checkingAnswer...")
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
    <button type="button" class="go">Go</button>
</div>

<div class="button">
    <button type="button" class="go">Go</button>
</div>

<div class="button">
    <button type="button" class="go">Go</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had previously tried using querySelectorAll, but that did not work at all. I have now tried it your way and it works, but again only for the first question. Clicking Go on question 2 still has no effect...

Comment: what if you `console.log()` what's returned by `document.querySelectorAll('.go')`?
Is more than one element being returned?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who helped. I have solved my issue now using jquery. This was the code I used:

```
$(".container").on("click", "button", function (e) {

    var container = $(e.target).closest(".container");

    if ($(container).find("input:checked").hasClass("right")) {
        $(container).find("img").show();
        $(container).find("button").remove();
        $(container).find(".radio").html('<h2 style="color: green;">Correct!</h2>');
        score++;
    } else {
        $(container).find(".radio").html('<h2 style="color: red;">Incorrect</h2>');
    }
});
```